# Getting Undefined offset when trying to echo result from a query

Tags: php, pdo

```
require("connections.php");
$sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT `title` FROM `movie` ORDER BY `movie_id` LIMIT 4 ");
$sql->execute();
while($row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $title[]=$row['title'];
}
```

As you can see i am trying to fetch titles from a table called movie and display it somewhere in my page.But the problem i am facing is that

```
 <ul id="right-sliding-navigation">
       <li class="sliding-element"><a href="#"><?php echo $title[0] ?></a></li>
       <li class="sliding-element"><a href="#"><?php echo $title[1] ?></a></li>
       <li class="sliding-element"><a href="#"><?php echo $title[2] ?></a></li>
       <li class="sliding-element"><a href="#"><?php echo $title[3] ?></a></li>
</ul>
```

it should display the last 4 items from my table but instead it displays the three item and on the fourth i am getting `undefined offset 3` error.Why am i getting the fourth error have no idea.I have looked into the other question related to undefined offset on here but can't seem to fix my error.Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Do you have 4 records in the `movie` table?

Comment: yeah I have more then 4 records in the `movie` table

Comment: Your error message says the index is `4`. Your code only uses `0, 1, 2, 3`.

Comment: Isn't it possible to just do `$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` and then echo `$row[0]['title']`

Comment: Can you use `print_r($title)` so you can see what your `title` array looks like?

Comment: That error would come from `$title[4]`.

Comment: @Maantje He would have to use `$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` for that.

Comment: Arent you missing the semi colon ; at the end of [title];

Comment: `var_dump($title)` showing the last three result .I don't know why it's not showing the fourth

Comment: Sorry that was a typo @Barmar

Comment: @Nitin `;` is optional before `?>`

Comment: @ToniReese For some reason the query is only returning 3 rows, unless there's code you haven't shown us that's reading one of the rows before the loop.

Comment: Could it be that $title[3] is null? Record missing in db? Column set to NOT NULL at create could prevent nulls.

Comment: @Nitin the title is set to Not NULL and there are more then 100 of records i have in my table.

Comment: @Barmar Whatever i had on that page i posted on here

Comment: Did you var_dump($row); to check if it is db related or script related?

Comment: @Nitin Why would a `NULL` cause a problem like this? There's nothing in the query or PHP that would skip nulls.

Comment: @Barmar i thought setting a null value in an array at the end might be disregarded

Comment: I don't see any way this error could happen if this is all the code and the table has at least 4 rows. There's no `WHERE` clause in the real query? What happens if you run the query in MySQL Workbench or PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: @Barmar it's strange if i run that query in mysql workbench it's returning the four result as expected

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Are you sure PHP is connecting to the same database?

Comment: @Barmar nvm you were right.i used `$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` twice.one before the loop and one inside the loop.so it was reading one column before the loop.

Comment: What happens if you change the query to `LIMIT 4 OFFSET 5` just to see if there's something strange with the original results you're getting?